# How to use session in BigQuery java client

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I want to create and then use temporary tables in multiple queries using java client. For that I need to use sessions.

I can create the temp table with:

```
BigQuery bigQuery = ....
QueryJobConfiguration.Builder b = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder("CREATE TEMP TABLE _SESSION.tmp_01 AS SELECT .....")
bigQuery.query(b.setCreateSession(true).build())
```

Problem is, how can I reuse the session in a next query?

```
b = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM _SESSION.tmp_01");
bigQuery.query(b.build()); //ERROR: cannot find tmp_01 table.
```

Answer (score 0):

Will JobStatistics.SessionInfo work for you?

```
 bq.create(
        JobInfo.of(QueryJobConfiguration
        .newBuilder("your query")
        .setCreateSession(true)
        .build()))
      .getStatistics[com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobStatistics.QueryStatistics]
      .getSessionInfo
      .getSessionId
```

Comment: and what to do with the session ID? How to use it with the next query?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/com.google.cloud.bigquery.QueryJobConfiguration.Builder#com_google_cloud_bigquery_QueryJobConfiguration_Builder_setConnectionProperties_java_util_List_com_google_cloud_bigquery_ConnectionProperty__

Put it here with "session_id" key. Using https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/com.google.cloud.bigquery.ConnectionProperty.Builder#com_google_cloud_bigquery_ConnectionProperty_Builder_setKey_java_lang_String_